# Excel If Statements

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to create an excel formula to get it to search a row for the word "Yes". If that word appears it is to pull the text from another cell. The formula works if I only have the first two conditions but once I add the third I receive an error message. Is there another way to get this formula to work?

```
=IF(AND(Cabinets!G2="Yes",Cabinets!G3="Yes",Cabinets!G4="Yes"),Cabinets!B2,Cabinets!B3,Cabinets!B4)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What error is shown?

Comment: "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

Comment: Your if functions has 4 arguments. It only takes 3. If G2 to G4 are yes what are trying to show? Same question for if one of them is No.

Comment: If G2 to G4 read as "Yes" then I need the text in the corresponding B2 to B4 cells to populate. My project has several tabs (cabinets, countertops, etc). In the example provided I am looking at cabinets. I will have several different cabinet options. If we select "Yes" for a specific cabinet, I need that price to appear on my main log to get a complete price for the project.

Comment: If it's a school/university project, no one will help you. Edit your question to show a sample of your data and the expected results

Comment: "If G2 to G4 read as "Yes" then I need the text in the corresponding B2 to B4 cells to populate." Which cells should get the results from B2 to B4?

Comment: so you want the sum of the B2:B4 where G2:G4 is `Yes`?  If so you want SUMIFS.

Comment: I have attached links to a couple of images. Image one is my main log and image two is the cabinets tab. I did delete out a couple of unimportant cells so the B/G has changed. The "Yes" cell is now in row D. I do not want to sum anything. I just need data transferred from one page to another based on selection. This is actually for work.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screen shots.

```
=INDEX(Cabinets!$A:$A,MATCH("Yes",Cabinets!$D:$D,0))
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer,